# Can't load image in local with Javascript

Tags: javascript

As my title above..

I can't load my image in my folder, but whenever I load image from http or from my Internet it works!

that must be something that i missed right?

***my codes here's just a part from my whole codes. maybe its collide with the 
other Javascript/html?

Should I put specific direction to my image that I aim? How to do that?

So the JS can detect the direction and ext?

```html
   var images = {
  image: [

     {src: '../images/gallery-1.png', alt: 'Project 1'}
    , {src: '../images/gallery-2.png', alt: 'Project 2'}
    , {src: 'https://unsplash.it/400/303random', alt: 'Project 3'}
    , {src: 'https://unsplash.it/400/304?random', alt: 'Project 4'}
    , {src: 'https://unsplash.it/400/305?random', alt: 'Project 5'}
    , {src: 'https://unsplash.it/400/306?random', alt: 'Project 6'}
    , {src: 'https://unsplash.it/400/307?random', alt: 'Project 7'}
    , {src: 'https://unsplash.it/400/308?random', alt: 'Project 8'}
    , {src: 'https://unsplash.it/400/309?random', alt: 'Project 9'}

  ]
};

function onClick(element) {
  document.getElementById("img").src = element.src;
  document.getElementById("modal").style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<div class="row">

<section class="w3-content w3-container w3-padding-64">

  <!-- Responsive Grid. Four columns on tablets, laptops and desktops. Will stack on mobile devices/small screens (100% width) -->
  <div class="w3-row-padding w3-center" appml-data="images">

    <div class="w3-col m4 w3-padding-16" appml-repeat="image" style="cursor: pointer;">
      <img src="{{src}}" alt="{{alt}}" style="width:100%" onclick="onClick(this)" class="w3-hover-opacity" style="cursor: pointer;">
    </div>

  </div>
</section>
<!-- End Container (Projects) -->

<!-- Modal for full size images on click-->
<div id="modal" class="w3-modal w3-black" onclick="this.style.display='none'" style="z-index: 9999999;">
  <span class="w3-closebtn w3-hover-red w3-text-white w3-xxxlarge w3-container w3-display-topright">×</span>
  <div class="w3-modal-content w3-animate-zoom w3-center w3-transparent w3-padding-64">
    <img id="img" style="max-width:100%">
  </div>1
</div>


  <script src='https://www.w3schools.com/appml/2.0.3/appml.js'></script>

</div>
```

Comment: Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors. The dev tools provide an **Inspector** / **Elements** and a **Network** tab. Please confirm: Is the resource _found_ (e.g. HTTP 200 response)? If not, which _actual URL_ is requested? Also, where and how do you set the first `<img>`’s `src`?

Comment: it says
Empty string passed to getElementById().

what should I correct? I'm not that expert about JS @Xufox

Comment: None of the code you’ve shown produces this warning. Where and how do you set the first `<img>`’s `src`?

Comment: my codes above just a part from my whole codes.
maybe its collide with the other Javascript/html?
can you give me your Facebook? So i can give me my whole codes?
@Xufox

Comment: or should I make some specific direction to the image that I want to aim? How to do that?